# String concating using linux pipe

Tags: linux, shell

Script:

```sh
env|grep JAVA_HOME|cat >>aa.txt
```

aa.txt will get values: JAVA_HOME=...
How can I script to get values as: export JAVA_HOME=...
This script is wrong:

```sh
env|grep JAVA_HOME|cat 'export'$0>>aa.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` utility:

```sh
env|grep JAVA_HOME|awk '{print "export "$0;}'|cat >> aa.txt
```

`$0` - means printing all the input columns (default column separator is space)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command to get the required output

```
 $ env | grep JAVA_HOME | sed 's/.*/export &/' | cat >> aa.txt
```

.* represent anything from the output
& represent all in the first field of .*.

Answer (score 1):

For the general case, including the possibility of more than one matching line for the `grep` and that you might want to do complex work on each line, you can feed a pipe to a loop:

```
env | while read line; do echo "export ${line}"; done
```

Alternatively, you could use `sed`:

```
env | sed "s/^/ export/"
```

(`^` indicating start-of-line.)